# Eclipse Plugin Open a PDF file from inside a plugin package

Tags: eclipse, pdf, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to open a PDF file that represents the documentation of my plugin from inside a package, since I have opened a properties file the same way using `getClass().getResource(URI)`.
I am trying the same with the PDF file, and I'm trying to get the URL of the file, then passing it to `Desktop.browse()` converted to URI, but it gives me a `Malformed URI` exception. Is there a way to do this easier and also to work?

This is my code so far:

```java
try{
        URL url = new URL(getClass().getResource("Documentation.pdf"), null);
        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(url.toURI());
    }catch(Exception exception){
        Status status = new Status(IStatus.ERROR, Activator.PLUGIN_ID,  exception.getLocalizedMessage(), exception);
        ErrorDialog.openError(null, "Error", "Error occured!", status);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL/URI you get back from `getResource` uses the `bundleresource` scheme which is not understood by many things.

For an Eclipse plugin you should use the `FileLocator` class.

```java
Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(getClass());

IPath path = new Path("path relative to root of the plugin");

URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, path, null);

URL fileURL = FileLocator.toFileURL(url);

Desktop.getDesktop().browse(fileURL.toURI());
```

Again the URL returned by `FileLocator.find` uses a special scheme and is not understood by many things. `FileLocator.toFileURL` converts this URL to a normal `file` scheme - to do this it may be necessary to unpack the file from the plugin jar to a temporary location.

Note: `Path` is `org.eclipse.core.runtime.Path`

Comment: What is the parameter type I should use for `Path`, it seems it does not accept any string arguments.

Comment: This is `org.eclipse.core.runtime.Path` **not** `java.nio.file.Path`

Comment: That was it. Also, `Desktop.browse()` has the error `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method browse(URI) from the type Desktop`

Comment: There is only one thing though. I've exported and installed the plugin into Eclipse, and it gives `NullPointerException` to this file, I should make a dependency into my `plugin.xml`?

Comment: Make sure that all resource directories are listed in the 'build.properties' - if they are not in that file they won't be in the exported plugin.

Comment: Yeah, i checked them into the `binary build`. Thanks again.